# Accessing a JPG file's properties on Windows

Tags: files-and-directories, windows

On Windows, a JPG file contains various properties (Title, Subject, Rating, Tags, Comments,...) that may be viewed and changed by right-clicking on the file in Explorer and selecting Properties, and then selecting the Details tab. How can I read and write these properties from within Mathematica?

Comment: The function option should be [`MetaInformation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MetaInformation.html)

Comment: @vipa Please consider making that comment into an Answer with examples.